# Kotlin Flow - is there anything similar to LiveData's emitSource?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I have a function that takes a parameter function returning a Flow,

```
fun <T> resultFlow(
  query: () -> Flow<T>,
  ... other parameters
): Flow<T> {
  return flow {

    val source = query()

    //!!!!    emit(source)   // I want something like emitSource like livedata has

   ...
   }
```

Is there anything that can be done to flow to be able to be sent like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to emit all items from a Flow, that's exactly what [`emitAll()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/emit-all.html) does:

```
fun <T> resultFlow(
  query: () -> Flow<T>,
  ... other parameters
): Flow<T> {
  return flow {

    val source = query()

    // Note that this will suspend until all values from the flow are collected.
    emitAll(source)
}
```

Comment: What if i don't want to make emitAll suspend same as emitSource() ?